# Set Theory. Power Set Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For any set $A$, prove that the cardinality of $A$ is no larger than the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you find an injective map $f:A\to P(A)$?

Comment: For future reference, it's considered bad etiquette on Math.SE to post a homework question without detailing what you have tried to solve the question on your own.

Comment: This is a standard "cantor diagonal" argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: For each $a$ in $A$, the powerset $\mathcal{P}(A)$ contains the element $\{ a \}$.